# Trying to use my iPhone to debug my apps from Xcode

Tags: ios

When I try to add my iPhone by

1. List item
2. plugging it in
3. open the organizer window from Xcode
4. click the + button (add to member center).
5. I now get the following error saying my iPhone sdk does not match the Xcode's

installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is available here.

Iphone model 4

OS Installed on Ted’s iPhone
7.1.1 (11D201)
iPhone 4
Xcode Supported iOS Versions
(nothing listed)

When I go to the download button for Xcode I do not see anything for upgrade and the Xcode is the same version I have
5.1.1

I did notice that on the right it says the Xcode is using 7.1  while my iPhone has 7.1.1 is this the reason?

How can I get my iPhone sdk to be compatible with Xcode so I can start debugging my program?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the iOS SDK for simulator in xcode. On xcode toolbar, click on the simulator list and then check list of available iOS SDK.

[image]

If iOS 7.1 is not present there, then you need to have updated xcode. Latest version of xcode is 5.1.1.

UPDATED:

If u didnot find any arrow after iPhone then open **Preferences**. Click on Xcode on top bar then select Preferences and then click on Download tab and then click on "Check and Install" button.

Comment: Hi, i do not have the check list of available iOS sdk, i do not have a arrow after iPhone..iphone retna etc?????? help